# a-b trees reason for requirement of a <= (b+1)/2

Tags: data-structures

The definition of a-b trees says

1. `2 ≤ a ≤ (b+1)/2`
2. Each internal node except the root has at least a children and at most b children.
3. The root has at most b children.

Now can anyone explain the reason for the requirement `a ≤ (b+1)/2` ?.

Comment: Since an `(a,b)` tree has all of the leaves at the same depth, `a` will always be smaller than or equal to `(b+1)/2`. Not sure how else to explain it, it's like this by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Well `a≤(b+1)/2` is equivalent to `2a≤b+1` or `2a-1≤b`.

The interval from `a` to `2a-1` is the smallest interval for which the rebalancing algorithm used for (a,b) trees actually work. Picking actual value for b greater than the minimum can affect the space utilization in the nodes and the complexity of the actual rebalancing part in the delete/insert operations but the algorithm will still work.

Lets say for example `a=k` and `k>=2`. If we pick value for `b` less than `2a-1`say `2a-2=2k-2`.

The Insert rebalancing part says :

If the node you are inserting into already has b keys and they become `b+1`.

```
If the overflowing node is the tree root :
    create two new nodes, copy into each half the root entries
    put into the root pointers to these two new  nodes with the key that separates them.

Else 
    create a new node 
    move half of the entries of the overflowing node into the new node
    insert a pointer to the new node in the upper neighbor
```

Now if `b=2a-2` overflow occurs when you need to add one entry in node with `2a-2` entries leaving you with `2a-1` entries total. If you split the node one of the nodes will be left with less than `a` entries creating an underflow in the node which is a problem. If `b` was the minimum possible value for `b` which is `2a-1` then overflowing node will have "total" `2a` entries which you can split into two nodes which have exactly the minimum `a`.

Edit:
For more concrete example lets say you could make a (a,b) tree with `a=3` and `b=4` which is less than `2a-1`. Then If you want to store exactly 5 values in your tree how are you going to do it? You cant put all the values in one node because they are more than 4. But you cant split into two nodes either because only one of the two nodes will have 3 entries and the other will be underflowing(2 entries only which is prohibited).

Another simple example is if `a=2`, then the minimum value of `b` is 3. If `b` was 2 this means that the node must have always 2 entries which is not achievable.